# Windows 10 Storage Space keeps getting disconnected

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, storage-spaces

I have 5 hdd drives on an external enclosure connected via USB 3. These drives are all pooled into a parity type storage space.

It's all working fine until I try move large amounts (500gb) of data to it. The storage space usually registers as disconnected around 10% of the transfer.

I already tried using a third party file copy app to move the files to no avail. (i.e. TeraCopy)

I wonder if this is a setup limitation?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you powering the drives?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment earlier. I posted a comment on Emile's answer which should answer your query.

Comment: I somehow chanced on an error on the Storage Spaces configuration window and googled it. It led me to this support page which has a very long list of complaints. 

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f4f3b96-4787-4f94-ad37-4d30d9939cdc/troubleshoot-storage-spaces-parity-pool-quotoffline-due-to-critical-write-failuresquot?forum=win10itprohardware

TLDR; Apparently my best option now is just to get real raid setup.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they disconnect is a lack of power.

The enclosure will probably have just enough power to keep them spinning in idle.

But like you said when a heavy load is on the hard drive, it will demand more power.

Most enclosures have a rating of 80W (5V x 16A), a hard drive uses around 15W when normally used but this can go up to 25W.

To protect your enclosure, it will cut the power of the heaviest user.

The solution to this is buy another enclosure or power 1 or 2 drives externally.

Same problem with a hub.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I am not sure of the wattage of my enclosure. It's this enclosure btw, https://www.amazon.com/ORICO-Aluminum-3-5-inch-Enclosure-Support/dp/B00JLFMVUW/ 

I have another 2 bay drive enclosure, I will try to install 2 drives in there to see if your theory is correct.

Comment: I think it's going to work, the enclosure has 72W only

Comment: Well, It didn't work.

Comment: On what did you test it? The first enclosure or another enclosure.

Comment: 2 drives in the 5 bay enclosure and 2 drives on a 2 bay enclosure, to make sure the drives has enough power.